# Views not interactive inside ViewPager android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

**I have a Fragment A,**

**Then i did two things :**

1. I attached that Fragment A inside viewPager.
2. I attached that Fragment alone on an activity.

**Observations :**

**A.** When I attached inside ViewPager:
The fab button that i have inside the fragment were interactive and when i press the button the data change in the layout as they were supposed to change.

**B.** When I attached inside Activity directly:
The fab button was not iterative and the data did not change in layout

**P.S.** -> It is the same fragment.java file I am attaching in both cases.

So what  can be the reason behind the two anomalous behavior ?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Is fab button inside the fragment or in an outsider layout?

Comment: inside fragment layout.

Comment: have a look at [this](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Floating-Action-Buttons)